# Javascript Error on Website

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm getting this Javascript error on my website (http://beta.radonsystems.net):

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'b.support' [undefined] is not an object.
```

With the jQuery Fancybox plugin.

This error is preventing the rest of the scripts running correctly.

Any ideas of how I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: That's not the error I get: Error: $(".thumbs").tabs is not a function
Source File: http://beta.radonsystems.net/
Line: 179

Comment: hmm :/ jQuery is instantiated.

Comment: I think jquery is loaded. Your tabs plugin is not. If jquery wasn't loaded, it would tell you $ is not defined.

Comment: You don't seem to have the actual jQuery library.

Comment: I'm using a prebuilt library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery tabs plugin is missing causing other errors. That is my final answer. :)